# Magento > 2.1.7 admin 404 (2.1.8 and 2.1.9)

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, 404

With the 2.1.9 and 2.1.8, i just can't access back-office... Even on a clean install.

When i install 2.1.7, or any previous versions, all is ok. I even tried to update a project that is actually on 2.1.7, and i'm facing the same problem...

I'm on a Apache/2.4.10 + PHP 7.0.6

Does anyone faced this pb ?

Edit: it's a Magento 404 error, not an Apache one.

Comment: did you check your admin name inside `app/etc/env.php`

Comment: Yep. All is ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pb came from **core_config_data**

- on a fresh, clean 2.2.2 install, both *web/secure/use_in_frontend* and *web/secure/use_in_adminhtml* were at NULL... Not 0, not 1, NULL... That was the pb.
- on the project i had to migrate from 2.1.7 to 2.2.2. This time, it was the *web/unsecure/base_url* that was not in the table...

I don't want to understand why.

Ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

I started mine with 2.1.8 and update it using update wizard Inside the admin magento and all have been completed without any issue. Do you take a look at the php setting?

Comment: In fact, I had the pb since 2.1.8 :) But view my answer, it's just crazy. I don't understand why a clean install do that... And in my migration case, *unsecure_url* was not set from the beginning... and used to work without it... not since 2.1.8 !

Comment: Does you magento give you install success? Which panel or OS are you using?

Comment: Yep, successful install, through web, not composer. Ubuntu 16, Apache.